# How to load into specific tab after refresh using angular material tabs?

Tags: angular16, angular-material-tab

I need to be able to load to specific tab after navigating away and back my tabs component or refreshing the page.

I am being able to store the last current tab in local storage

```html
<mat-tab-group #tabGroup (selectedTabChange)="tabChanged($event)">
    <mat-tab label="Overview">1</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Overview">2</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Overview">3</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Overview">4</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

```
tabChanged(tabChangeEvent: MatTabChangeEvent): void {
  localStorage.removeItem('lastTab');
  this.theIndex = tabChangeEvent.index;
  localStorage.setItem('lastTab', this.theIndex);
}
```

now when coming back to the page or refresh I need to reload the page to that tab index saved in local storage, how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MatTabsGroup has a input called `selectedIndex`: https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview

```
The active tab may be set using the selectedIndex input or when the user selects one of the tab labels in the header.
```

So you can use that in your template:

```
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex" (selectedTabChange)="tabChanged($event)">
  <mat-tab label="Overview">1</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Overview">2</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Overview">3</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Overview">4</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

And in ts, when you first load your component, get the index you saved in localStorage in OnInit:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    const savedTabIndex = localStorage.getItem('lastTab');
    this.selectedIndex= savedTabIndex;
  }
```